# Отображение 3d модели в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, blender

В программе на WPF нужно добавить окно, в котором будет отображаться 3д модель какого-либо объекта, например, куба. Нужна возможность вращения и увеличения/уменьшения модели в данном окне, чтобы можно было лучше ее разглядеть.

Модель сделана в Blender, то есть ее можно сохранить в любом популярном формате 3д моделей.

Это возможно реализовать? Подскажите, как, или где это можно найти, а то сам ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: Посмотрите сайт [Чарльза Петцольда](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/08/A-Rotating-Solid-Cube-in-Silverlight-3.html). По [ссылке](http://www.charlespetzold.com/silverlight/RotatingCube/RotatingCube.html) как раз вращающийся куб. Ищите его книгу 3D Programming for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не охото самому реализовывать манипулятор и конвертацию модели из Blende, то можно попробывать HelixToolKit https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit
На мой взгляд самая вменяемая библиотека для работы с 3D графикой для WPF.